# how to fix this installation error on windows

Tags: flutter, dart

I hit a problem very early on in the official tutorial for using Flutter.  Specifically, when I run Flutter Doctor I get this error message:

X Downloaded executables cannot execute on the host.
See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information

When I follow that link there is nothing there that looks relevant.  (It is mostly about LINUX problems)

Can anyone advise me on what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried installing the MSVC package? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: Reach out to Flutter

Comment: @DavidBrossard What's he best way of getting in touch with them?

Comment: @Vaiden Which one of these downloads are you expecting would help?  How come this would be a prerequisite without the installation instructions mentioning it?  IN any case I already have various Visual C++ distributables installed in my machine so I think this is unlikely to be the cause.  Do you have a particular reason for suspecting it?

Comment: This error seems to originate from missing GCC toolchains on linux. There is no GCC toolchain for Windows, the MSVC packages being the replacement.